# save a paint canvas without the background image

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I am new in Android development.

I am trying to save a bitmap from the canvas after doing some paint. the canvas is initiaised with an image. And then some simple paining... Now I want to save the new paining without the initialised image. Is it possible?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to use two canvases, one for background draw, one for other draw.

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent canvas, and put your background image underneath.